# Using Multiple login module in JBoss

Tags: java, authentication, ejb, jboss7.x, jaas

I am new to authentication and security area and I am trying to extend the authentication mechanism of my application, which currently provides traditional user name/password authentication, to provide user to authenticate via LDAP Server.

In the current implementation, the application uses *j_security_check* thread from Server API to authenticate the user. 
The *standalone.xml* file of Jboss has a login module pointing to a *myLoginModuleClass* class which extends the *jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule*.

```html
<security-domain name="db-domain">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="myLoginModuleClass" flag="required" module="packageForClass">
      <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256" />
      <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64" />
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

I have added another login-module called LDAP Login module in a separate security.

```html
<security-domain name="ldap-domain">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="LDAPLoginModule" flag="required" module="LDAPModulePackage">
      <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" />
      <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
      <module-option name="bindCredential" value="secret" />
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
    </login-module>
  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

The issue I am currently facing is following: the *jboss-web.xml* and the project's *web.xml* both points to existing security domain: db-domain. And I can only specify one security domain there. 
Question: How can I programmatically tell jboss to point to a particular login class based on user selection, meaning if user choose to go have ldap auth, the LDAPLoginModule class is called? Or is there any other better way to have a mix mode authentication?

Thank in advance

Comment: You trigger the form-based login by submitting the form to `j_security_check`, likewise, how do you trigger the LDAP login?

Answer (score 9):

Meanwhile, I found a work around. 
I can specify both the login module in single security domain and change the flag from "required" to sufficient".

```html
<security-domain name="common-domain">
  <authentication>
    <login-module code="LDAPLoginModule" flag="sufficient" module="LDAPModulePackage">
      <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory" />
      <module-option name="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
      <module-option name="bindCredential" value="secret" />
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
    </login-module>

    <login-module code="mydbLoginModuleClass" flag="sufficient" module="packageForClass">
      <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256" />
      <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64" />
      <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
    </login-module>

  </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

By doing this the jboss security will pick up the login sequentially in the order it is configured in standalone.xml file(first ldap and then dblogin) and stops whenever the login is successful

Answer (score 1):

For any web application say it is developed under JAVA, there is web.xml file where you can define multiple security role but Security authentication will be only one. So, that means at a time you can use only one security domain for your web application. Although JBOSS configuration file can have multiple Security domain but in your jboss-web.xml you can only use one. See, the below JBOSS documents for confirmation:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/6nisfjn8c/index.html
Go under Specifying an Authentication Mechanism:

So, in order to manage two login module below either things can be done (any one from below):

- Create custom login module and use your two login module logic into that (complex as developer should be aware about all methods of login (initialize, login, commit, abort).
- Add your login modules under same security domain and play with attribute named "flag".
  if flag-"sufficient" then that login module will not go down the stack if successful.For more information: check flag header-> https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Security_on_JBoss-Defining_Security_Domains.html

Answer (score 0):

I remember having researched on a similar problem an year ago and did not find a solution. A workaround that i applied is to have 2 sets of jboss-web.xml files, one configured with your db-domain and one with ldap-domain. When LDAP security is to be turned off, you simply run a script to replace the web xml with db-domain one and redeploy. This was feasible because the requirement was static and not user input based or dynamic.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comment, unfortunately,in my case the user input is dynamic plus redeploying the xml required jboss restart, which I can't do

Comment: Meanwhile, I found a work around. I can specify both the login module in single security domain and change the flag from "required" to sufficient". By doing this the jboss security will pick up the login sequentially in the order it is configured in standalone.xml file and stops whenever the login is successful.

Comment: Glad you found a work around. Could be helpful to me in the future. Thanks for sharing.