# How to change security-domain dynamically for JBoss6?

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, kerberos, adfs, jboss6.x

I want to implement ADFS SSO and kerberos on the same Jboss 6 server.

Create filter and on the basis of some condition it should authenticate either with ADFS or Kerberos.

So it should dynamically change security domain through java.

**Update:**
ADFS and kerberos auth is working separately. But I am able to configure one at time in login-module.xml file.

I tried this approach [Using Multiple login module in JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481177/using-multiple-login-module-in-jboss)

and configured ADFS and kerberos in the same file with multiple login-module but it every time invokes ADFS

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create your own custom JAAS module.

For Active Directory see examples like http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-active-directory-jaas-example-source-code

For Kerberos an example is here https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToImplementKerberosAuthenticationWithASimpleRESTWebApp

If are using a large amount of roles or organisations in your AD you might need to increase the default HTTP header size in JBoss. See Undertow documentation on for specifics.

If you are using example JAAS modules and they are not working a great tip is to set the logging level to TRACE to help you see where the problems are.